# Insert and Shift Down "X" Amount of Column Rows Under Specified Row

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

Currently I am working with very large sets of vehicle data with varying value amounts i.e the number of locations we have vehicles.

A large issue I am running into is blending two particular formats shown below as `SET-1` and `SET-2` to the `FINAL FORMAT`

`SET-1` with vertical headers following down column `A`

`SET-2` with horizontal headers across row `1`

```
                      *DATA SET-1*
|       |      A     |     B     |     C     |
|   1   |     VIN        12745       33166
|   2   |     LC1        GR/MI       LA/CA
|   3   |     LC2        AR/MI       SD/CA
|   4   |     LC3        LN/MI
```

```
                      *DATA SET-2*
|       |      A     |     B     |     C     |
|   1   |     VIN         LC1         MAKE
|   2   |    12745       GR/MI        FORD
|   3   |    33166       LA/CA        BMW
|   4   |    67832       CB/OH        GMC
```

The real road block that I'm running into is with `FINAL FORMAT` the Locations or `LC` needs to be positioned under one another in a blank row.

```
                     *FINAL FORMAT*
|       |      A     |     B     |     C     |
|   1   |     SKU         LC1         MAKE
|   2   |    12745       GR/MI        FORD
|   3   |                AR/MI        
|   4   |                LN/MI        
|   5   |    33166       LA/CA        BMW
|   6   |                SD/CA
|   7   |    67832       CB/OH        GMC
```

Instinctively what I want to do is on a new sheet, have all `VIN` numbers in  column `A` as they are in `SET-2` have `B1` Vlookup and Match the `VIN` of on column `B` of `SET-1` count how many items are under that `VIN` shift the rows down and display the `LC`'s in the newly created rows.

I sincerely apologize I have actually been working out how to work this and visually demonstrate what I am trying to do all day. I will be more than happy to provide any further information. I have over 20k VIN and 10-20 locations for each VIN.

Any help is beyond appreciated.

Comment: Should LC1 in dataset 1 be the same as LC1 in dataset 2? And if there is no match for VIN in dataset 1 (like 67832), should it just use LC1 from dataset 2?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I was concentrating so heavily on the the format over completed information. there is always a matching VIN for the LOCATIONS/ LC's. In my example `67832` shown in `DATA SET-2` row `4` would be in column `D` of `DATA SET-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with repeated index..match formulas:

In A2

```
=IF(ROW()=2,Sheet2!A$2,IF(ROW()-MATCH(99999,A$1:A1)<COUNTA(INDEX(Sheet1!A:C,0,
MATCH(INDEX(A$1:A1,MATCH(99999,A$1:A1)),Sheet1!$1:$1,0)))-1,"",INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,COUNT(A$1:A1)+2)))
```

In B2

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),INDEX(Sheet1!A:C,
ROW()-MATCH(99999,A$1:A1)+2,MATCH(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(99999,A$1:A1)),Sheet1!$1:$1)))
```

In C2

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"")
```

Assumes that LC1 in sheet1 is the same as LC1 in Sheet2, and so if there is no match for VIN in Sheet1, you take it from Sheet2.

I have added an extra row in Sheet2 to test the case where there is no match for VIN in Sheet1.

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

**Sheet3**

[image]